# Unable to reach local server configured on https port 443 with subject alternative name

Tags: iis, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, subject-alternative-name

I created a CA with OpenSSL and created and signed a server certificate with it. I gave three subject alternative names to the server certificate, providing its common name as the server itself (the common name for the CA and the server certificate are the same).
When I use the comon name to connect, it all works. But if I try one of the subject alternative names, it fails saying DNS probe finished. Essentially it just does not find anything for the address.
What am I missing?

Comment: You do need to configure DNS to map the right IP address to that subject alternative name. Run a report and it should tell more https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: The correct server IP is provided with the subject alternative names but I still can't reach the server through the SAN.

Comment: could you please provide the certificate and how you are conning detail? which error you are getting? try to use the network monitor to capture some network trace. which browser you are using? did you try any other browser?